# How to count number of occurrences of data combinations and save in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a problem in which I try to create a matrix with the number of occurrences of specific 'coordinates'. I am working in R.

To illustrate, this is (part of) my data:

```
pre = c(3,1,3,2,2,4,3,5,3,4,6,5,6,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,5,7,6,7,7,7,4,8,4,8,8,4,4,8,3,9,8,6,9,8)
post = c(4,3,5,3,4,6,5,6,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,5,7,6,7,7,7,4,8,4,8,8,4,4,8,3,9,8,6,9,8,8,9,7,9,9)
df = data.frame(pre,post)
```

I then define this output matrix with the possible coordinate dimensions(range 1-20 in all data):

```
matrix = matrix(NA, nrow=20, ncol=20)
colnames(matrix) = seq(1,20,1)
rownames(matrix) = seq(1,20,1)
```

I then need a loop to run through my data and to store how many of the specific pre-post combinations exist within the data:

```
for (i in 1:40){matrix[df$post[i], df$pre[i]] = 1}
```

This works as in that the output now shows which 'coordinates' occurred in the data, but it doesn't say how many times.
For example, I know that pre=4, post=4 occurred twice.
Thus the loop needs to remember the combination already occurred and needs to add one more 1, but I don't know how to program this.

I hope somebody can be of help,
Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize the matrix with zeros instead of `NA` and then increment the matrix value like this:

```
pre = c(3,1,3,2,2,4,3,5,3,4,6,5,6,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,5,7,6,7,7,7,4,8,4,8,8,4,4,8,3,9,8,6,9,8)
post = c(4,3,5,3,4,6,5,6,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,5,7,6,7,7,7,4,8,4,8,8,4,4,8,3,9,8,6,9,8,8,9,7,9,9)
df = data.frame(pre,post)

matrix = matrix(0, nrow=20, ncol=20)
colnames(matrix) = seq(1,20,1)
rownames(matrix) = seq(1,20,1)

for (i in 1:40){matrix[df$post[i], df$pre[i]] = matrix[df$post[i], df$pre[i]] + 1}
```

By the way, the setting of the matrix `colnames` and `rownames` is not needed if you don't need it for any other reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It indeed works. 
I do have an additional question. In the whole dataset, also zeros occur. R defines the rows/columns starting from 1, thus using matrix = matrix(0, nrow=21, ncol=21) doesn't solve the problem. Do you perhaps have a suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: I succeeded in working around that issue. I have changed all original zeros in the dataset to 21, then setting the matrix to 21 rows and 21 columns. After looping, I order the 21st row and column (which actually portrays the combinations for zeros in my data) to be the first row and column in the matrix (matrix2 = matrix[c(21, 1:20), c(21, 1:20)]). Then renaming the columns and rows from 0 to 20.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` to do this.  Convert the 'pre', 'post' columns to `factor` with `levels` specified as 1 to 20 and then use `table`

```
table(factor(df$pre, levels = 1:20), factor(df$post, levels = 1:20))
```

---

If we are using the already created 'matrix' an option is

```
out <- as.data.frame(table(df))
matrix[as.matrix(out[1:2])] <- out$Freq
```